# On preg match php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need help creating a regular expression

```
blah blah blah blah <?= __l(array('key'=>'SOMEVALUE','default'=>'string string string')) ?>blah blah
```

I want to be able to strip the 'SOMEVALUE' and the 'string string string'

Thanks
In advance

======  'This is what I have'  ========

```
$subject = "Blah blah ja ja blah blah jank junk jonk <?= __l(array('key'=>'KEYKEYKEY','default'=>'I am a monkey sigh\'s')) ?> ldjlsakfdj as;dfj as;flkj a fsd  ljaasfd <?= __l(array('key'=>'KEYKEYKEY','default'=>'I am a monkey sigh\'s')) ?>  ";
$pattern = '#\_\_l\(array\(\'key\'=>\'(.*)\',\'default\'=>\'(.*)\'\)\)#';



if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject)) {
print "A match was found.";
} else {
print "A match was not found.";
}

print '<br />';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is a bit too complicated, try something like this:

```
$regex = "/'key'=>'[^']+','default'=>'[^']+'/";
$string = preg_replace( $regex, "'key'=>'','default'=>''", $string);
```

The regex is:

```
'key'=>'        - Match this literally
[^']+           - Match anything that's not a single quote, one or more times
','default'=>'  - Match this literally
[^']+           - Match anything that's not a single quote, one or more times
'               - Match this literally
```

And the replacement is simply the 2nd parameter to [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I came up with:

```
$pattern = '#\_\_l\(array\(\'key\'=>\'(.*?)\',\'default\'=>\'(.*?)\'\)\)#';
```

but I like you answer better **nickb** so I'll vote your up